# Android custom image on/off button

Tags: android

I want to create custom ImageButton, but to work like on/ off button. On click on button image to be changed to pressed(until another button is pressed)!

On picture This month button is on , This year off .

How can I create button like this?

Do I need to use  and how ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergey Glotov and wheaties thanks  for your help

For every ImageButton I create separate selectors for default and pressed state, I create ImageButton in xml:

```
                   <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/month_button"
                    android:id="@+id/btnMonth"
                    android:onClick=ButonMonthClick"/>
```

And onClick event for all ImageButton I change background image programmatically:

```
        btnWeek.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.week_pressed);
    btnMonth.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.month_default);
```

Thant solve my problem!

Comment: Don't change the resource manually. That's what the selector is for. See @wheaties answer.

Comment: But I want "On click on button, image to be changed to pressed(until another button is pressed)" but selector doesn't save its state.

Answer (score 8):

Use the selector XML tag to help you achieve this.  Here, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) link about [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)s.  So their example shows

a button.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and then links an actual button to that xml:

```
<Button
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Comment: I think `ToggleButton` would be better in this case.  http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Comment: @Sergey Glotov the toggle button is the one with a "light" affixed to the middle.  If you want your own custom button with custom graphics when you click, you're going to have to go with a selector.  I'm often wrong.  If you know something more, post a solution.  I'd love to see it too.  I'm still learning Android myself.

Comment: But the selector doesn't save its state?

Comment: I try different methods and I think Sergey Glotov is right "selector doesn't save its state". My solution is above